poner coto a /ponerle coto a
I know the phrase ''ponerle coto a'' means to put a stop to something negative.
For example,
''Necesitamos ponerle coto a los botellones''. I believe sometimes the ''le'' is not needed.
I see in Babla online dictionary ,examples,
poner coto al comercio ilícito
Hay que poner coto a eso.
Es bueno poner coto a estas prácticas inmorales.
Creo que tenemos que poner coto a esta situación.
Hemos de poner coto a estas prácticas desleales.
When is it needed or is it optional?
Is it Direct/Indirect object related?
If so, is it ''necesitamos ponerle coto a los botellones'' but ''A los botellones necesitamos poner coto''?
Perhaps,this is nonsense. I have studied D.O. and I.D.O  but that was a simpler form. This is more advanced.

Poner coto a: This phrase is used to indicate putting a stop to something directly. For example, “Tienes que poner coto a su insolencia” means “You have to put a stop to his insolence.”
Ponerle coto a: The addition of “le” is a dative pronoun that can add emphasis or formality to the expression. For example, “Alguien, antes o después, tendrá que ponerle coto a esto” means “Someone, sooner or later, will have to put a stop to this.”

So,does that mean it really is optional? Like you said ,more for emphasis and formality? I resarched what a''dative pronoun ''is ,one that comes after  a verb and refers to the same  person as the subject. So,what is ''le'' referring to hear ,is it''la insolencia''? In which case,why  isn't it  ''la'' to mean ''it''?



The addition of “le” only adds emphasis or formality.


The indirect object pronoun “le” is used regardless of the gender of the noun it refers to. So, it is always “le” and never “la” when referring to an indirect object.
• “Le di el libro a María.” (I gave the book to María.)
• “Le compré un regalo a Juan.” (I bought a gift for Juan.)


For direct objects, the pronouns “lo” and “la” are used depending on the gender of the noun:
• “Lo vi.” (I saw him/it - masculine.)
• “La vi.” (I saw her/it - feminine.)

Ok,yes,thank you.I understand that again . Lastly, for other phrases ,is it common to introduce ''le'' into the phrase like ''ponerle coto''. I can't recall seeing phrases used like this.Perhaps, you could give me examples of common phrases that native speakers often include ''le'' with them.

Phrases that are quite common in everyday conversation:

Ponerle coto - To put a stop to something.
Echarle ganas - To put effort into something.
Hacerle caso - To pay attention to someone.
Darle vueltas - To think something over.
Echarle la culpa - To blame someone.
Tenerle miedo - To be afraid of someone or something.
Pedirle perdón - To ask for forgiveness.
Hacerle daño - To hurt someone.
Darle igual - To not care about something.
Echarle un vistazo - To take a look at something.


YeS ,they are great. I realise I know all these already but hadn't thought about it.thank you

Respuesta y comentarios copiados de ChatGPT

As we can read here, adding "le/s" is usually optional but sometimes advisable or even necessary. I don't think it adds any formality or emphasis. The only emphatic use arises when the full indirect object is placed at the beginning and then there appears the redundant pronominal object as a necessary particle:

A estas prácticas debemos ponerles coto.

If not preposed, the indirect object may or may not be accompanied by the pronominal object:

Debemos poner(les) coto a estas prácticas.


Ok,thanks. So,it is clear it is necesary to make it plural like all normal agreement rules where it applies. I had wondered about that too.

@Gustavson: The difference between your sentences is the emphasis:

“A estas prácticas debemos ponerles coto.” The indirect object pronoun “les” is attached to the verb “poner” and refers back to “estas prácticas.”
“Debemos poner(les) coto a estas prácticas. This sentence emphasizes the action “debemos poner coto” (we must put a stop) by placing it at the beginning.”


@user37164 To me, "debemos poner coto a estas prácticas" and "debemos ponerles coto a estas prácticas" sound exactly the same, with no addition of emphasis or formality whatsoever in the latter case.
